# android view dosen't draw correctly

Tags: android, xml, view, draw

xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/frame_living_root_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       >

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/player_surface"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />


        <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />


        <com.netease.nimlib.sdk.avchat.model.AVChatSurfaceViewRenderer
            android:id="@+id/video_render"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone" />


        <com.netease.nimlib.sdk.avchat.model.AVChatSurfaceViewRenderer
            android:id="@+id/bypass_video_render"
            android:layout_width="110dip"
            android:layout_height="150dip"
            android:layout_gravity="right|end|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="70dip"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:visibility="gone" />


     <!--root view is FrameLayout with 40dip layout_margin and is a little complex-->
        <include layout="@layout/layout_live_top" />


    <!-- the content of this view will be scroll by touch event-->
        <com.example.SimpleSlideView
            android:id="@+id/slide_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- yellow background-->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/yellow_child_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#ff0" />
        </com.example.SimpleSlideView>
    </FrameLayout>
```

SimpleSlideView:

```
public class SimpleSlideView extends FrameLayout {

    public int screenWidth;
    public int screenHeight;
    private float lastY;

    public SimpleSlideView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initScreenSize(context);
        scrollTo(0, screenHeight);
    }

    private void initScreenSize(@NonNull Context context) {
        DisplayMetrics dm = context.getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        screenWidth = dm.widthPixels;
        screenHeight = dm.heightPixels;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        float rawY = ev.getRawY();

        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                lastY = rawY;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                final int delta = (int) (rawY - lastY);
                scrollTo(0, getScrollY() - (delta));
                lastY = rawY;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                scrollTo(0, screenHeight);
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

I want to write a SimpleSlideView that can scroll it content down by pull down on it SimpleSlideView works as expected in lightweight XML but a little weird in complex XML.

@layout/layout_live_top contain a FrameLayout  root view  with 40dip layout_margin and layout_live_top is a little complex.

SimpleSlideView is a MatchParent view without padding and margin, same with it child @+id/yellow_child_view which has a yellow background.

Something weird is happen when quickly pulldown:

[image]

The yellow area has 40dip margin left and right at the beginning of the pull and then it become match parent.SimpleSlideView seems to be affected by the margin(40dip) of other view, it should be matched parent while pulling down.I don't know why this happened.It is because of my complex XML?

Comment: try to override `onMeasure()` in your view and calculate its width and height and set with the help of  `setMeasuredDimension(int measuredWidth, int measuredHeight)`

Comment: @Lucky.I have check the value of getMeasuredWidth() and child.child.getMeasuredWidth() in SimpleSlideView's drawChild() method,both value are 1080(resolution of my phone is 1920*1080).